# how to call the class library from .js file in .net

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I need to call the Class library function from JavaScript file after some calculation are done. With some parameters.

The function is called after text is changed as bellow:

```
text.Attributes.Add("onchange", "calculate()");
```

After `calculate()` is done from the .js file I want to call the Class Library.
Is this Possible to achieve, Please help to solve this.

I tried to call it by onchange but already using it to call JS function.

```
text.Attributes.Add("onchange", "text_change(text)");
```

Comment: Is this a webforms or mvc application?

Comment: Using webforms to call JS file

Comment: Call a method directly in a library/dll deployed in the server from client javascript/browser?!

Comment: when text changed in the textbox I need to call the method. the text box is created dynamically in C#, which runs on server side.